# Index Was Outside The Bound of Array In Java script C# Web Application Creating Google Chart?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-visualization

hi i got this error in java script i am trying to run from server side in this script i use for loop in which i  get value for loop runs more then 3000 times and get value from array having mare then 3000 values my script is,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
        data.addRows(count);
        for (var i=0;i<count;i++)
        {
        data.setValue(i, 0, '"+Dvar[i]+"');
        data.setValue(i, 1, "+Pvar[i]+");
        }
        var chart = new    
                google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240, title: 'Company Performance'});
      }
    </script>
```

i am using this script server side so this script is in the string and count is mentioned oudside this script as array (Dvar) and (Pvar) and count value would be more then 3000
or is there any error in this script  regarding loop hopes for your suggestions..

Comment: Its time to put your browser's spell checker to work ;)

Comment: @Shekhar i do not understand what you want to say? please tell breifly

Comment: And where is `count` defined ?

Comment: I don't see that there is enough info here.  You're asking about a for loop.  I see only one loop in the included code, but we don't have any way to see the count variable or where it came from.  To get help here, I think you're going to have to describe more what this code is doing and include enough that someone could actually see how it works.  Otherwise, this will probably just get downvoted as not answerable with the info provided.

Comment: Count is define outside the script as array Dvar and Pvar count value would be more then 3000

Comment: @jfriend i make "count" clear in my post!

Answer (score 0):

You said count is defined as an array, then you problem is this line:

```
 for (var i=0;i<count;i++)
```

you cant use count directly for count's length, it should have been

```
 for (var i=0;i<count.length ;i++)
```

Comment: for some time i have change count to 5 any where in my code and try to run but i am getting error "i" does not exsis in the current context ??

Comment: `change count to 5 `  ??? First clear this thing.. The variable count is defines as `var count = 5` or `var count = []` . Which one is it?

Comment: if there would any error i am getting is due to count then for checking i replace count by 5 in my loop,                                        for (var i=0;i<5;i++) but actually count is int variable having 3000 value leave count and i mention loop i use 5 in place of count then again it is giving error i does not exsis in the current context ???

Comment: and you get a new error for `i`.. is it so ? check you code dear.. there is something you haven't shown us here

Comment: @Shekar i think you havent seen the line i have changed for for loop()   for (var i=0;i<5;i++) here i have declared "i" and getting error for i does not exsis ?? if i change my code and remove loop and use hardcode value insplace of it then my code runs fine means there would be error in loop i have inserted !